# Why does this recursive quick sort program not work?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, recursion

I'm trying to implement quick sort in java and practise but for some reason this code does not even enter the while loop marked below with the comment and it does not really sort the array.

```
public class Solution2 {
    private int[] ar;
    Solution2(int [] ar) {
        this.ar = ar;
    }
    public  void quickSort(int left, int right) {
        if ((right - left) <= 0) {
            return; } 
        else {
                int pivot = ar[right];
                int partition = partitionIt( right, left, pivot);
                quickSort(left, partition-1);
                quickSort(partition, right);}
    }   

    public  int partitionIt ( int leftptr, int rightptr, int pivot) {

        int left = leftptr-1;
        int right = rightptr; 
        while (true) { 
            while (right > 0 && ar[--right] > pivot)  // Code does not loop through to the small elemen
                ;
            while (ar[++left] < pivot) ; 
            if (left >= right) {
                break;
            }
            else {
                swap(left, right);
            }
            swap(left, rightptr);
        }
        return left;
    }

    public  int[] swap (int dex1, int dex2) {
        int temp = ar[dex1];
        ar[dex1] = ar[dex2];
        ar[dex2] = temp;
        return ar; 
    }



    public void printArray() {
        for(int n: ar){
            System.out.print(n+" ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

}

public class Immplementer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();
        int[] ar = new int[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            ar[i]=in.nextInt(); 
        }
        Solution2 soln = new Solution2(ar);
        soln.printArray();
        soln.quickSort( 0, ar.length -1 );
        soln.printArray();
    }    
}
```

*Please note this is not a question about how Quick Sort works but this about this particular error that I was unable to figure. Kindly help.*

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: Why do you have semicolons at the end of the line that your while loops are on?

Comment: Yes i did but I figured my typo and I cant help to keep cursing myself ever after. .

Comment: Incorrect Code: _int partition = partitionIt( right, left, pivot);_                     correct code: int partition = partitionIt( left, right, pivot);

Answer (score 1):

Code works fine except for one mistake:

```
int partition = partitionIt(right, left, pivot);
```

Instead, it should be:

```
int partition = partitionIt(left, right, pivot);
```

Comment: If this is it, please consider accepting the answer.